# Can we call a JavaScript Facebook API Call within another API call.Throwing error: Invalid token: "307378872724184". An ID has already been specified

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using  JavaScript Facebook SDK to export data from my website to Facebook.

I have a condition where if a user who tries to export data onto the Group don't have permission then i want to send a invite to that user to join the group so that he can export data to group page.

The problem is when i try to call a group API call within another like i called group API invite user inside group API feed call and its is showing error like "invalid token: "3073788727XXXXX". An ID has already been specified." where that id is my Facebook group id.

CODE:

```
function postWallGroup(group_id,topicContent) {
        params = {
            message: topicContent,
        };

        FB.api(
                'https://graph.facebook.com/' + group_id + '/feed/',
                'post',
                params,
                function(response) {
                    if (!response) {
                        alert_4a('Error occurred.');
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        if(response.error.message === 'You do not have permission to post in this group.'){
                                FB.api('/me', function(response2) {
                                //getting user details to send invite      
                                finviteId = response2.id;
                                    //do invite user stuff here;
                                    FB.api(
                                    'https://graph.facebook.com/'+group_id+'/members/',
                                    'post',
                                    {
                                        id: finviteId,
                                    },
                                    function(response3) {
                                        if (!response3) {
                                            alert_4a('Error occurred.');
                                        } else if (response3.error) {
                                            alert_4a(response3.error.message);
                                        } else {
                                            alert_4a('Success fully invited data to facebook group page.')
                                        }
                                    }
                                    );
                                });
                            alert_4a(response.error.message+'<br/>'+'An invite has been sent to join this group. Only members of this group can export data.');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert_4a('Success fully imported data to facebook group page.')
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: To invite a user to a group, you need to use the app access token. And that should never be in client-side code (because every user could see it there). So if you want to invite a user to a group, you have to do that server-side.

Comment: thanks CBroe i am doing server side after doing that in client side and thanks, yes you are correct this operation needs to performed at server side.will update my question after doing server side code...thanks for support... i am doing this API stuff for the first time...